# How to analyze SQL data over a union with missing values?

Tags: sql, vertica

Note: This data is obfuscated, so it might not make much sense.

I have two tables of source data. Table `meter_increment` holds a timestamp and an increment of value on the (water) meter since previous record. Table `meter_billing_sessions` contains events that denote times when the water consumption is being billed, in separate sessions. It holds a timestamp and session ID. I have an union of data in these tables that look roughly so, ordered by timestamp (*make sure to scroll to the right to reveal my notes*):

```
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------+
| eventType      | dataSource  | sessionId |            amount |      timestamp |
|----------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------|
|                | WATER_METER |           |             82700 |  1588047625320 | \
|                | WATER_METER |           |            124928 |  1588049228489 |  |
|                | WATER_METER |           |            749568 |  1588060228780 |  | - SUM these 
|                | WATER_METER |           |            139264 |  1588066837299 | /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | eda6a919  |                 0 |  1588071842076 | <-- start of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |           6601728 |  1588071842250 | \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | eda6a919  |                 0 |  1588072173722 |  \
|                | WATER_METER |           |           7202816 |  1588072173930 |   \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | eda6a919  |                 0 |  1588072738485 |    | - SUM these
|                | WATER_METER |           |          16607232 |  1588072738634 |   /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | eda6a919  |                 0 |  1588073073864 |  /
|                | WATER_METER |           |          12030976 |  1588073074009 | /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | eda6a919  |                 0 |  1588073142312 | <-- end of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |            616448 |  1588073142489 | \
|                | WATER_METER |           |             32768 |  1588075199418 |  | - SUM these
|                | WATER_METER |           |              4096 |  1588075423888 | /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 2d54d918  |                 0 |  1588077038705 | <-- start of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |           5370880 |  1588077038845 | \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 2d54d918  |                 0 |  1588077039792 |  \
|                | WATER_METER |           |            176128 |  1588077039868 |   \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 2d54d918  |                 0 |  1588077113129 |    | - SUM these
|                | WATER_METER |           |            823296 |  1588077113216 |   / 
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 2d54d918  |                 0 |  1588077541749 |  / 
|                | WATER_METER |           |          22238208 |  1588077541880 | /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 2d54d918  |                 0 |  1588077858532 | <-- end of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |          32056564 |  1588077858642 | \
|                | WATER_METER |           |          24623884 |  1588077858642 |  \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 130759f4  |                 0 |  1588078142145 |   | SPECIAL case,
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588078142229 |  /   SUM together
|                | WATER_METER |           |          66718720 |  1588078142229 | / 
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 6178b903  |                 0 |  1588078472832 | <-- start of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |         105058304 |  1588078472903 | \
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588078472903 |  \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 6178b903  |                 0 |  1588079039102 |   \
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588079039224 |    \
|                | WATER_METER |           |          52585472 |  1588079039224 |     \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 6178b903  |                 0 |  1588079375536 |      | - SUM these
|                | WATER_METER |           |          38905856 |  1588079375649 |     /
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588079375649 |    /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 6178b903  |                 0 |  1588079941631 |   /
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588079941748 |  /
|                | WATER_METER |           |          40554496 |  1588079941748 | /
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 6178b903  |                 0 |  1588080274318 | <-- end of billing
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588080274406 | \
|                | WATER_METER |           |          19591168 |  1588080274406 |  \
| BILLING_ACTIVE |             | 902359b4  |                 0 |  1588080842532 |   \ SPECIAL case,
|                | WATER_METER |           |                 0 |  1588080842666 |   /  SUM together
|                | WATER_METER |           |              1024 |  1591372498349 |  /
|                | WATER_METER |           |              2048 |  1591372525838 | /
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+----------------+
```

The first `BILLING_ACTIVE` event with a particular `sessionId` means the start of billing of the water consumption in a given session, the last event with the same `sessionId` means the end of the billing.

I want to sum up all `amount`s that occurred inside a billing session (doesn't have to be split per sessionId), so that I can know how much water was consumed during billing session and how much outside billing sessions.

There is a special case, if there is a single billing event for a particular sessionId, then the data "around" it is to be regarded as *NOT* part of a billing session (think of it as instantaneous start and of billing). Only data in-between `BILLING_ACTIVE` sessions with the same `sessionId` are considered as being part of a billing session.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I need to be able to tell if the `amount` is `billed` like this:

```
+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
|    billed | eventtype      | datasource   | sessionid   |    amount |            ts |
|-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------|
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |     82700 | 1588047625320 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |    124928 | 1588049228489 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |    749568 | 1588060228780 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |    139264 | 1588066837299 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | eda6a919    |         0 | 1588071842076 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |   6601728 | 1588071842250 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | eda6a919    |         0 | 1588072173722 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |   7202816 | 1588072173930 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | eda6a919    |         0 | 1588072738485 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  16607232 | 1588072738634 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | eda6a919    |         0 | 1588073073864 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  12030976 | 1588073074009 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | eda6a919    |         0 | 1588073142312 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |    616448 | 1588073142489 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |     32768 | 1588075199418 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |      4096 | 1588075423888 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 2d54d918    |         0 | 1588077038705 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |   5370880 | 1588077038845 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 2d54d918    |         0 | 1588077039792 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |    176128 | 1588077039868 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 2d54d918    |         0 | 1588077113129 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |    823296 | 1588077113216 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 2d54d918    |         0 | 1588077541749 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  22238208 | 1588077541880 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 2d54d918    |         0 | 1588077858532 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |  32056564 | 1588077858642 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |  24623884 | 1588077858642 |
|     False | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 130759f4    |         0 | 1588078142145 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588078142229 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |  66718720 | 1588078142229 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 6178b903    |         0 | 1588078472832 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             | 105058304 | 1588078472903 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588078472903 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 6178b903    |         0 | 1588079039102 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588079039224 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  52585472 | 1588079039224 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 6178b903    |         0 | 1588079375536 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  38905856 | 1588079375649 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588079375649 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 6178b903    |         0 | 1588079941631 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588079941748 |
|      True |                | WATER_METER  |             |  40554496 | 1588079941748 |
|      True | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 6178b903    |         0 | 1588080274318 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588080274406 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |  19591168 | 1588080274406 |
|     False | BILLING_ACTIVE |              | 902359b4    |         0 | 1588080842532 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |         0 | 1588080842666 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |      1024 | 1591372498349 |
|     False |                | WATER_METER  |             |      2048 | 1591372525838 |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi Michal - you can UNION SELECT the two tables together - and put NULLs where you have gaps with no problems. But I can't really grasp which end report you expect... Do you want to GROUP BY sessionid? Can you at least show one or two rows of the expected report?

Comment: Thanks for the modification. But something is even more puzzling than before. `False` in `amount`, I can relate to, somehow, even if you mix Boolean-s with numbers. But I can't understand the rule or logic behind `True` directly followed by a number, like in `True76128` . Can I ignore these, and just inspire myself on the new column `billed` in the report?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was doing some search&replace to save manual labour when adding `billed` column, and I clearly messed it up. There should be no booleans in `amount`.

Answer (score 0):

Without your answer, I can only imagine that you need to find an identifier to group together the groups you marked as having to be summed.
Vertica has two session identifier generators that I haven't seen anywhere else so far:

`CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT()` and `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT()`.

They are OLAP functions. They start and reset to 0 at every `PARTITION BY` and increment by one each time something is true or something changes, respectively.

In your case, I'd `UNION SELECT` the two tables as you did, using NULLs where not applicable. Then run a select around this union, generating a new session identifier every time the session id is not NULL. Finally, select again from this select, grouping by the obtained session identifier, SUM()ming the amount, and adding the minimal and maximal timestamp of that group for documentation purposes.

Here are the two input tables as an in-line `SELECT` :

```
WITH
meter_increment(dataSource,amount,timestamp) AS (
          SELECT 'WATER_METER',82700,1588047625320
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',124928,1588049228489
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',749568,1588060228780
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',139264,1588066837299
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',6601728,1588071842250
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',7202816,1588072173930
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',16607232,1588072738634
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',12030976,1588073074009
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',616448,1588073142489
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',32768,1588075199418
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',4096,1588075423888
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',5370880,1588077038845
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',176128,1588077039868
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',823296,1588077113216
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',22238208,1588077541880
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',32056564,1588077858642
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',24623884,1588077858642
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588078142229
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',66718720,1588078142229
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',105058304,1588078472903
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588078472903
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588079039224
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',52585472,1588079039224
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',38905856,1588079375649
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588079375649
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588079941748
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',40554496,1588079941748
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588080274406
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',19591168,1588080274406
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',0,1588080842666
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',1024,1591372498349
UNION ALL SELECT 'WATER_METER',2048,1591372525838
)
,
meter_billing_sessions(eventType,sessionId,amount,timestamp) AS (
          SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','eda6a919',0,1588071842076
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','eda6a919',0,1588072173722
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','eda6a919',0,1588072738485
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','eda6a919',0,1588073073864
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','eda6a919',0,1588073142312
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','2d54d918',0,1588077038705
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','2d54d918',0,1588077039792
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','2d54d918',0,1588077113129
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','2d54d918',0,1588077541749
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','2d54d918',0,1588077858532
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','130759f4',0,1588078142145
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','6178b903',0,1588078472832
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','6178b903',0,1588079039102
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','6178b903',0,1588079375536
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','6178b903',0,1588079941631
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','6178b903',0,1588080274318
UNION ALL SELECT 'BILLING_ACTIVE','902359b4',0,1588080842532
)
```

The select below is from those two tables:

Editing the solution based on your answer; it seems, re-reading it, that you also need your original session id in the report. For that, the session id, which you only get in the billing event, not in the measure, needs to be in the same group as its predecessor rows and be obtained with a `MAX()` expression; so the Boolean expression changes so that the preceding `sessionId` needs to be NOT NULL.

```
WITH
combo (eventtype,datasource,sessionid,amount,ts) AS (
SELECT
  NULL
, datasource
, NULL
, amount
, timestamp
FROM meter_increment
UNION ALL SELECT
  eventtype
, NULL
, sessionid
, amount
, timestamp
FROM meter_billing_sessions
)
,
sessionized AS (
SELECT
  CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(LAG(sessionid) IS NOT NULL) OVER(w) AS sess_id
, *
FROM combo
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
)
SELECT
  sess_id
, MAX(sessionid) AS sessionid
, MIN(ts) AS measure_start_ts
, MAX(ts) AS measure_end_ts
, SUM(amount) AS billed_consumption
FROM sessionized
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;
-- out  sess_id | sessionid | measure_start_ts | measure_end_ts | billed_consumption 
-- out ---------+-----------+------------------+----------------+--------------------
-- out        0 | eda6a919  |    1588047625320 |  1588071842076 |            1096460
-- out        1 | eda6a919  |    1588071842250 |  1588072173722 |            6601728
-- out        2 | eda6a919  |    1588072173930 |  1588072738485 |            7202816
-- out        3 | eda6a919  |    1588072738634 |  1588073073864 |           16607232
-- out        4 | eda6a919  |    1588073074009 |  1588073142312 |           12030976
-- out        5 | 2d54d918  |    1588073142489 |  1588077038705 |             653312
-- out        6 | 2d54d918  |    1588077038845 |  1588077039792 |            5370880
-- out        7 | 2d54d918  |    1588077039868 |  1588077113129 |             176128
-- out        8 | 2d54d918  |    1588077113216 |  1588077541749 |             823296
-- out        9 | 2d54d918  |    1588077541880 |  1588077858532 |           22238208
-- out       10 | 130759f4  |    1588077858642 |  1588078142145 |           56680448
-- out       11 | 6178b903  |    1588078142229 |  1588078472832 |           66718720
-- out       12 | 6178b903  |    1588078472903 |  1588079039102 |          105058304
-- out       13 | 6178b903  |    1588079039224 |  1588079375536 |           52585472
-- out       14 | 6178b903  |    1588079375649 |  1588079941631 |           38905856
-- out       15 | 6178b903  |    1588079941748 |  1588080274318 |           40554496
-- out       16 | 902359b4  |    1588080274406 |  1588080842532 |           19591168
-- out       17 |           |    1588080842666 |  1591372525838 |               3072
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, and I apologise for not being clear enough in my intentions. Your assumption is correct, I need to group the data in `meter_increment` by `sessionId` from `meter_billing_session`.
I will try to adapt your solution to my real application, but from the start it looks very promising to what I intend to do.

Comment: Just changed it to allow for your original `sessionId` to be included in the report

Comment: > Just changed it to allow for your original sessionId to be included in the report
Will give this a try.

I've edited the post to show how I need to be able to split the data